# C++ - How to program functions that work on temporaries and don't allocate

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, rvalue, expression-templates

I am trying to implement a fixed size array class that will represent small size vectors.
I wanted to have typical vector operations defined, like multiplication by scalar and sum with another vector.
The problem is I cannot get the same performance with these two codes:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    vout[i] = (k[0][i] + 2*k[1][i] + 2*k[2][i] + k[3][i])/6;
// vs
vout = (k[0] + 2.0*k[1] + 2.0*k[2] + k[3])/6.0;
```

The reason is that the second option is creating more arrays in the process, while the first adds in place.
I would like to know if there is a way to write a function that operates on temporaries (r-value references) so that a sum is performed over the temporary, without allocating an extra vector.

My current code:

```cpp
template<class T, int N>
class SVec {
  public:
    inline T& operator[](int i) { return mdata[i]; }
    inline const T operator[](size_t i) const { return mdata[i]; }
    inline T* data() { return mdata; }
    inline T const* data() const { return mdata; }

    inline SVec& operator+=(const SVec& rhs) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] += rhs.mdata[i];
        return *this;
    }
    inline SVec& operator-=(const SVec& rhs) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] -= rhs.mdata[i];
        return *this;
    }
    inline SVec& operator*=(T rhs) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] *= rhs;
        return *this;
    }
    inline SVec& operator/=(T rhs) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] /= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    inline SVec& fma(const SVec& x, T y) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] += x[i]*y;
        return *this;
    }

    inline SVec&& operator+(const SVec& rhs) && {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] += rhs.mdata[i];
        return std::move(*this);
    }
    inline SVec&& operator*(T rhs) && {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] *= rhs;
        return std::move(*this);
    }
    inline SVec&& operator/(T rhs) && {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] /= rhs;
        return std::move(*this);
    }


  private:
    T mdata[N];
};

template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator+(SVec<T, N> lhs, const SVec<T, N>& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}
// Tried:
// template<typename T, int N>
// inline SVec<T, N>&& operator+(SVec<T, N>&& lhs, const SVec<T, N>& rhs) {
//     lhs += rhs;
//     return lhs;
// }
// template<typename T, int N>
// inline SVec<T, N>&& operator+(const SVec<T, N>& rhs, SVec<T, N>&& lhs) {
//     lhs += rhs;
//     return lhs;
// }
// template<typename T, int N>
// inline SVec<T, N>&& operator+(SVec<T, N>&& lhs, SVec<T, N>&& rhs) {
//     lhs += rhs;
//     return lhs;
// }
template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator-(SVec<T, N> lhs, const SVec<T, N>& rhs) {
    return lhs -= rhs;
}
template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator*(SVec<T, N> lhs, T rhs) {
    return lhs *= rhs;
}
tem
plate<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator*(T rhs, SVec<T, N> lhs) {
    return lhs *= rhs;
}
template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator/(SVec<T, N> lhs, T rhs) {
    return lhs /= rhs;
}
template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> operator/(T rhs, SVec<T, N> lhs) {
    return lhs /= rhs;
}

template<typename T, int N>
inline SVec<T, N> fma(const SVec<T, N>& x, T y, SVec<T, N> z) {
    return z.fma(x, y);
}

template<int N>
using DoubleVec = SVec<double, N>;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the technique known as [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik And I think the *[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)* matrix library is an example; looking around a bit I found that https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html gives an explanation of what's special about the implementation.

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik. My question was more a technical question: how to declare a function that receives a temporary vector, modifies it and returns a reference to that temporary so that at most one temporary is created in an expression like `v1+v2+v3+v4`. If you know the answer to this (or know that it's currently not possible), I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: However, expression templates are more powerful, because they allow to transform the operation tree (for instance: `(scalar*Matrix)*Matrix` -> `scalar*(Matrix*Matrix)`). That is, they act as a macro on the abstract syntax  tree. It was very educational reading about them, and if you want to write an answer I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I think technically you can do something like `SVec&& operator+(SVec&& lhs, const SVec& rhs) { lhs += rhs; return lhs; }` (you'd need similar overloads for the temporary on the right-hand side, both sides, and neither side). Off the top, I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried but I get conflicting signatures:

`error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘SVec<double, 4>’ and ‘DoubleVec<4>’ {aka ‘SVec<double, 4>’})
   62 |         vout = (((k[0] + k[1]) + k[2]) + k[3])/6.0;

candidate: ‘SVec<T, N> operator+(SVec<T, N>, const SVec<T, N>&) [with T = double; int N = 4]’
    inline SVec<T, N> operator+(SVec<T, N> lhs, const SVec<T, N>& rhs) {
candidate: ‘SVec<T, N>&& operator+(SVec<T, N>&&, const SVec<T, N>&) [with T = double; int N = 4]’
    inline SVec<T, N>&& operator+(SVec<T, N>&& lhs, const SVec<T, N>& rhs) {`

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid the ambiuous overloads @IgorTandetnik?

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/6hq4aa). I think this calls copy constructor as few times as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to return the object which is modified on the original copy. Which cannot be done on a standalone operator+.

However there is the concept of return value optimization which may apply to your compiler depending on the usage, if you immediately return the result from a function which returns by value, it is possible that the compiler will optimize it not to store it on a temporary:
[Return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization)

I can see that your standalone operator+ only accepts the same type, so you can also make a similar `operator+(...)&` for as a class member and that can return itself. But this will bring more problems as shown below:

```
    inline SVec& operator+(const SVec& rhs)& {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) mdata[i] += rhs.mdata[i];
        return *this;
    }
```

This will not work correctly when you have a statement like this, but it will not create a new copy.

```
    SVec<int, 2> s1;
    SVec<int, 2> s2;
    SVec<int, 2> s3;
    s3 = s1 + s2;
```

Comment: My intention was specializing an operator when the parameter is a temporary, resulting in a modification of the temporary instead of the creation of another temporary vector and returning a reference to that temporary to chain operations.

Comment: However, expression templates, as suggested by @Igor Tandetnik are more powerful, because they also allow to modify the expression.